# Elements stick to each other horizontally instead of spreading verticlly (Nextjs + Tailwind)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've been trying to create sort of boxed with shadow containers. One at the top that containes input fields and another one under it containing a graph.

This is the code.

`

```
<div className="bg-grey w-screen h-screen m-10 shadow-lg"> {/* Background*/}
          <div className="flex justify-center"> {/* Center*/}
            <div className="bg-white w-3/4 h-1/4 rounded-2xl overflow-hidden mb-50 shadow-lg"> {/* Card*/}
              <InputForm/>  
            </div>
            <div className="bg-white w-3/4 h-1/4 p-20 rounded-2xl overflow-hidden mb-50 shadow-lg"> {/* Card*/}
              <ValueChart/>  
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

`

I'm tried to use grid instead of flex and chanigng the numbers. But nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox layouts arrange children in a row by default. You need to specify `flex-direction: column`. You can use tailwind's `flex-col` class to do this. I've also added the `items-center` class to center the items (this adds `align-items: center` to align the items centrally across the axis/direction. If you were laying them out in a row, i.e. without `flex-col` then you would use `justify-center` as you originally had).

CodeSandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-keldysh-dhw54f?file=/pages/index.js

```html
<div className="bg-grey w-screen h-screen m-10 shadow-lg"> {/* Background*/}
  <div className="flex flex-col items-center"> {/* Center*/}
    <div className="bg-white w-3/4 h-1/4 rounded-2xl overflow-hidden mb-50 shadow-lg"> {/* Card*/}
      <InputForm/>  
    </div>

    <div className="bg-white w-3/4 h-1/4 p-20 rounded-2xl overflow-hidden mb-50 shadow-lg"> {/* Card*/}
       <ValueChart/>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's solved part of the problem. It's still not in the middle.

Comment: @idobarabi upadted answer to center the cards